# How can I avoid using User IDs as user folder names in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

This is stated in the [Google Cloud Storage Naming Best Practices](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices) documentation.

> Don't use user IDs, email addresses, project names, project numbers, or any personally identifiable information (PII) in bucket or object names because anyone can probe for the existence of a bucket or object, and use the 403 Forbidden, 404 Not Found and 409 Conflict errors to determine the bucket or object's name. Also, URLs often end up in caches, browser history, proxy logs, shortcuts, and other locations that allow the name to be read easily.

This sort of puts a strain on where I was headed with my application, and how it is structure​d. I really want to avoid handling/storing Cloud Storage paths via CloudSQL or DataStore.

I'm writing this in Python on Google App Engine, and a good amount of my code for GCS is based off of the username as of right now. For example, a user would always upload his/her file within the folder (username) which he/she has registered as. A lot of the path logic I currently have, utilizes the User variable for GCS.

Could someone possibly recommend a way in which I would be following their guidelines, while still having the capability to use a single variable to call the a user directory? By that I mean without assigning the folder as the users ID. I would need to be able to reference this variable without accessing SQL or Datastore at any given time.

Any help would greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you salt and hash the username?

Comment: If you have a user entity, you could use the id of that entity in the path.

Comment: Will your application support users changing their username?  Maybe I formed an LLC and want to change my user name from MyName to MyLLCName.

Comment: @JeffreyRennie They will not be able to change their username. This would be done manually if need be.

Comment: "a user would always upload his/her file"...  Do you also put the original file name into the object name?

Comment: @Jeffrey Yes. The filename would stay in tact.

Answer (score 0):

Usernames and filenames can have PII.  For example: JeffreyRennieHasWarts.pdf.  So they all must be hidden.

One method is to encrypt the object names.  The good news is that Google just announced a Key Management Service that makes this a lot easier.  See:
https://cloud.google.com/kms/

Another method, as jterrace mentioned, is to salt and hash the username to create a user key.  It would look something like:

```
user_key = hmac.new("username", mysecretsalt, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

But that still leaves the problem of file names.  To hide the original file name, you'd give the objects meaningless names, and store a separate object whose contents are the original name of the file.  So your object names might look like

```
userkey1/GUID1.contents
userkey1/GUID1.name
userkey1/GUID2.contents
userkey1/GUID2.name
userkey2/GUID3.contents
userkey2/GUID3.name
```

The best choice will depend on how you plan to query the data stored in cloud storage.